# How to stop adding min.js in require.js load module

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, requirejs

I have been trying to load socket.io into my code. Seems require always adding -min.js as extension. I want to override this configuration. Can anyone guide me how i can do this?

neeed to remove addtion of min.js in require js.

```
var myRequire = require.config({
            paths: {
                'socketio': ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io']
            }


        });

        myRequire(['socketio'], function(io) {
            console.log(io);
            var socket = io.connect('http://10.0.1.112:3000');
            console.log('socket connected');
            socket.on('message', function(data) {
           console.log(data);
            });
        });
```

So it's alywas trying to load

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io-min.js?version=20151012172132
```

I want to over-ride the configuration to load .js file instead of -min.js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: RequireJS adds a `.js` extension but it does not add `-min` or `.min` or anything of the sort. You've got something else going on. The URL you are using in your `paths` gives a 404.

Comment: Nope Louis. I think we can customize what extension we need to add.

Comment: You're wrong. But what do I know? I'm just the [top answerer](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/requirejs/topusers) of RequireJS questions on this site.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Will try to find more on this and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't fresh but I am on hold project where we can't use r.js, so I use [Fine grained URL control](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#onejs)

See example for add `.min` on production (no debug):

```
if (!debug) {
    var load = requirejs.load;
    requirejs.load = function (context, moduleId, url) {
        //modify url here, then call original load
        let splited = url.split('.');
        if (splited[splited.length - 1] === 'js' && splited[splited.length - 2] !== 'min') {
            splited[splited.length - 1] = "min.js";
            url = splited.join('.');
        }
        return load(context, moduleId, url);
    };
}
//Call your first module
```